# Comparing Power Mosfets - value of Rg

Tags: power, mosfet, inverter

I want to build an inverter and currently I am in the processing of choosing the right MOSFET. To achieve this I use simulations to compare the total power dissipated on the MOSFETs, to see which one has the lowest.

In order to truly see the best results and the "competition" to be fair, should I be using the same value for Rg (let's say 10ohm), or should it be proportionate to each MOSFET's Qg. I'm thinking the by adjusting the Rg I am eliminating the Qg from the equation and the results will be based on Rdson.

Comment: Rg affects dampening. Assuming 100nH Inductance and 1nFarad Cgate in series with Cdg, 10 Ohms is a useful value. Are you also modeling inductances in the sims? Looking for sustained oscillation?

Comment: I am not modeling the inductances of the MOSFET, except the one on the load.

Comment: Just a quick question if you may answer. To calculate for example switch on time which is the correct formula? IG_Off  / Qg ? Where IG is gate current and Qg gate charge?

Comment: Rg is calculated according to max. gate driver current.

Comment: I know, but that was just a side note. I have seen in one of the courses at my college that formula, and I thought it may be incorrect. (the one in the comments)